# Building a custom aggregator based on CPP iterator with OpenMP

Tags: c++, performance, iterator, openmp

Following scenario:

- Simulation dealing with data on two different spatial resolutions
- An existing lookup table mapping the finer resolution data to the coarser data
- The recurring job of aggregating or distributing the data (different data to be exact) to the other scale

Instead of having to write the same two for loops etc over and over again I wanted to be able to write something like the following:

```
for(const auto gridcell& : iterator) {
   container[gridcell.id] = gridcell.map([] getRequiredData(CellRef cell){return cell->getSpecificData()})}
```

or with openMP

```
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = 0; j < iterator.size(); ++j) {
```

For example for every 0.5° grid cell I want to apply a lambda function to all beloningin 5' cells retriving the needed data and summing/averaging.. it up afterwards.

So far so good. I've implemented it and it is waaay slower than using two for loops (both implementations with #pragma omp parallel for).
All I've done so far is implement a custom iterator storing the information about the lookup table return a new GridItem on each iteration.

The implementation of the GridItem looks something like that:

```
    class FiveDegreeToZeroFiveItem {
private:
    AssociatedNodes nodes;
//Is called in public constructor not included here
    static AssociatedNodes getData(){
        AssociatedNodes out;
        std::vector<int> tmp;
        try{tmp = lu_table.at(pos);}
        catch (const std::out_of_range& oor){return out;} //No 5min nodes in 5min cell

        int i = 0;
        for (int id : tmp) {
            i = id_table.at(id);
            out.push_back(vector->at(i).get());
        }
        return out;
    }
//Other implementations like averaging etc. left out
    template <
        class ElemT,
        class FunctionT,
        class T = decltype(std::declval<FunctionT>()(std::declval<ElemT>())),
        typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<T>::value>::type
    >
    const T iterate(FunctionT fun) const{
        T val;
        for (int j = 0; j < nodes.size(); ++j) {
            val += fun(nodes.at(j));
        }
        return val;
    }
public:
//Constructor with call to private getData() omitted for readability


template <
        class ElemT,
        class FunctionT
    >
    const void map(FunctionT fun) const {
        iterate<ElemT>(std::forward<FunctionT>(fun));
    }
};
```

I left out some of the code reducing it to the essentials (If I missed something important I'd be happy to include that later on). It achieves what it was build for but as I mentioned way to slow.
Is there a general flaw in my approach? Or are there reasons why it is so much slower than two for loops? Is (wrong use of) openMP the reason?